# Auvidea B102 and rpi3 B

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, input-device

Hello I want to buy the auvidea HDMI to CSI-2 bridge and I want to know if it will work with my RPI because the website is not very helpful

EDIT
From what I read it looks like I need to buy the b101 to make it work with the standard rpi3 and also I need the one with the additional sound port to have audio or not?

Comment: Interesting looking device! I'd agree with you that their site is not the smoothest learning experience I've ever had. From what I can tell the B102's been designed with the Pi Compute Module in mind, while the B101 is intended for 'standard' Pi models. I'm not completely sure just how functional the whole approach is - there's a fairly epic thread on the [raspberrypi.org forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=120702), but it's not easy reading.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should work, from what I've seen, it acts just like a normal pi camera.

I first saw this product in a popular science magazine, and I also saw on their website that it was made for pi so it should have normal CSI-2 support and since it uses the CSI-2 it should be able to use anything that normally captures video from a Raspberry Pi.